# PXfilter<> datarec does not insert records into View

Tags: acumatica

I am creating records to be saved in memory and then displayed on a grid. All the fields are Unbound and should not be saved to SQL

DAC:

```
    [Serializable]
    [PXCacheName("AgeingDAC")]
    public class AgeingDAC : IBqlTable
    {

    #region UsrItemCode
    [PXInt(IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Item Code")]

    public virtual int? UsrItemCode { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrItemCode : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrItemCode> { }
    #endregion

    #region UsrItemDesc
    [PXString(255)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Item Desc")]

    public virtual string UsrItemDesc { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrItemDesc : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrItemDesc> { }
    #endregion
    }
```

I have made a view that should store records in memory

```
public class StockAgeing : PXGraph<StockAgeing>
{

    public PXSave<AgeingDAC> Save;
    public PXCancel<AgeingDAC> Cancel;

    public PXFilter<AgeingFilter> MasterView;
    public PXFilter<AgeingDAC> DetailsView;
}
```

When inserting new AgeingDAC records into the DetailsView the data does not want to insert into the cache

```
AgeingDAC insertedRecord = DetailsView.Cache.Insert(newRec) as AgeingDAC;
```

Answer (score 0):

`PXFilter` can only have one record.
You need to use regular views with `PXVirtualDAC` attribute.

```
[PXVirtualDAC]
public SelectFrom<AgeingFilter>.View MasterView;

[PXVirtualDAC]
public SelectFrom<AgeingDAC>.View DetailView;
```

Answer (score 0):

`PXFilter` is made to contain only one record. This is how you could do it:

```cs
public class StockAgeing : PXGraph<StockAgeing>
{
    public PXSave<AgeingDAC> Save;
    public PXCancel<AgeingDAC> Cancel;

    public PXFilter<AgeingFilter> MasterView;

    [PXVirtualDAC] // ensures graph doesn't try to save these rows into a database
    public PXSelect<AgeingDAC> DetailsView;

    public IEnumerable detailsView()
    {
        // create your rows. 
        // you can create them right here
        // or create a separate class to do it, like in an example:
        var ageingRows = MyService.GetAgeingRows(MasterView.Current);

        foreach (var ageingRow in ageingRows)
        {
            yield return balance;
        }
    }
}
```

`MyService` is a placeholder, you can create your rows right there inside the method itself, or create any new class that will contain logic for data creation (what I'd choose).
You can go further with this template if you want - you can add logic to try to find records in Cache before trying to create them again. This will help if you don't want the grid to be just read-only and want to edit those rows.